# Invalid Constructor Error for Pundit Policy Scopes when using OR (logical union) queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, authorization, pundit

I'm seeing this kind of error:

```
Invalid #<GroupPolicy::Scope> constructor is called
```

but it's very strange because removing the [or()](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) method seems to bypass the error - but I need this method to find Groups that belong to a particular user AND find Groups that a particular person can edit, and return that set to the index page. The user in this case is a PORO populated with employee data from an AREST service. I don't think I'm using the method incorrectly because the error thrown is related to Pundit.

Application Policy:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :context, :record

  def initialize(context, record)
    @context = context
    @record = record
  end

  delegate :user, to: :context
  delegate :cookies, to: :context

  ...

  class Scope
    attr_reader :context, :scope

    def initialize(context, scope)
      @context = context
      @scope = scope
    end

    delegate :user, to: :context
    delegate :cookies, to: :context

    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end
end
```

Group Policy:

```
class GroupPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  ...

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        super
      else
        scope.joins(:group_editors).where(group_editors: { editor_id: user.id })
        # the above line works, but it doesn't work when I try:
        # scope.joins(:group_editors).where(group_editors: { editor_id: user.id }).or(scope.where(owner_id: user.id))
        # both queries succeed individually if I print them each on a new line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Group Model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :group_editors
  has_many :contents
end
```

Editors Model:

```
class GroupEditor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Groups Controller (index):

```
def index
  @groups = policy_scope(Group)
  redirect_to group_path @groups.first if @groups.count == 1
end
```

Pundit User (uses additional context because we read cookies when doing auth sometimes):

```
def pundit_user
  UserContext.new(current_user, cookies)
end

class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :cookies

  def initialize(user, cookies)
    @user = user
    @cookies = cookies
  end
end
```

**Edit #1**

This seems to work - but why?

```
scope.joins(:group_editors).where('owner_id = ? OR group_editors.editor_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
```

**Edit #2**

The real error is

```
Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]
```

which is unfortunate. Pundit throws a misleading error.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential issue I see here is that you are calling scope twice. Worth a try...

```
scope.joins(:group_editors).where(group_editors: { editor_id: user.id }).or(scope.where(owner_id: user.id))
```

Could this be rewritten like this

```
scope.joins(:group_editors).where(group_editors: { editor_id: user.id }).or(Group.where(owner_id: user.id))
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, I had tried that. See my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in master and will be part of the next release.